# How to replace <NA> with a number for a single factor variable in R?

Tags: r

- Data: dat
- Variable: v1
- I have tried this, but it did not replace "< NA >" (no spaces)

  ```
  cwm$v1 <- factor(cwm$v2)
  replace(cwm$v1, cwm$v1=="< NA >", 9)
  ```

Again with no spaces. It gives me back the variable still with "< NA >"

Comment: `cwm$v1[is.na(cwm$v1)] <- 9`. See `?is.na`.

Comment: try `is.na(cwm$v1)` for the condtition?

Comment: The trouble seems to be that it is <NA> and not NA - The is.na function is not altering the <NA> values.

Comment: @GeorgeTarr that's because you don't understand how factors work. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `<NA>` is a missing value in a factor:

```
> factor(c("a",NA,"b"))
[1] a    <NA> b   
Levels: a b
```

Hence you can simply use `is.na` like for all missing values, but you likely see this:

```
> v1 <- factor(c("a", NA,"b"))  
> v1[is.na(v1)] <- 9
> v1
[1] a    <NA> b   
Levels: a b
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(v1), value = 9) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

The reason is simple: 9 is not a level of that factor. So in order to get this done, you need to do this replacement BEFORE you convert to a factor:

```
> v2 <- c("a",NA,"b")
> v2[is.na(v2)] <- 9
> v1 <- factor(v2)
> v1
[1] a 9 b
Levels: 9 a b
```

Now you have 9 as a separate level. If you don't want this, you shouldn't use a factor in the first place. So in case you start from a factor, convert to `character` first:

```
> v1 <- factor(c("a", NA,"b"))
> v1 <- as.character(v1)
> v1[is.na(v1)] <- 9
> v1
[1] "a" "9" "b"
```